# Regular expression to match the string before third occurrence of : colon

Tags: python, regex

I would like to have all the string before third occurrence of :

```
Q: asd:rad:asd:ad asd:fztf:123
A: asd:rad:asd
```

I am using something like:

```
[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*
```

which gives me answer:
ad asd:fztf:123

any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the regex. You must be using it wrong.

Comment: Match 1
Full match 0-11 `asd:rad:asd`
Match 2
Full match 11-23 `:ad asd:fztf`

it shows the two match instead of one...

Comment: `^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*` https://regex101.com/r/9RW53K/1

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is almost perfect. You just need help to match the beginning of the line by using the anchor `^`

```
^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*
^---- Here
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/7YS2nn/1/)**

Update: just noticed [Gurman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5331061/gurman) suggested this in his comment, hence his credit

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this, although I don't know if it's the best: `^.*?:.*?:.*?(?=:)`

`^` indicates only search in the start of the string.

`.*?:` indicates whatever followed by :. We want it twice. Note the `?` to make the expression don't greedy.

`.*?` basically the same as the line before but not capturing the `:`.

`(?=:)` is a positive look-ahead. It means that after the captured regex there will be a `:` but it should be not captured.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a non-regex way also:

```
string = """
Q: asd:rad:asd:ad asd:fztf:123
A: asd:rad:asd
"""

splitted = [":".join(line.split(":")[:3]) 
                for line in string.split("\n") 
                if len(line) > 1]

print(splitted)
# ['Q: asd:rad', 'A: asd:rad']
```